# How to make content change per click on a button without loading a new page

Tags: html

Pretty sure its a dumb question but after a long search i didnt find anything.

While browsing the League of Legends page i noticed something i would like to replicate on my own page.

link:http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/page/champion-reveal-illaoi-kraken-priestess

In the middle of the page there is a video and text beneath, it also shows 5 buttons everyone of them represents another video and a text. If you press one of the buttons the text and video changes smoothly but it doesn't load a new page or anything. How is this achieved iam not getting it out of the source code. I hope somebody can help. Is this achievable without Javascript?

Does somebody know a tutorial which deals with that?

Thanks for help.

Edit: Maybe if this question is inapproriate for this forum is there some kind of webdesign forum for stupid beginner questions?

Comment: It's JavaScript. If you turn js off, that page no longer works.

Comment: There are overlapping slides and when you click on the buttons one is faded out and the other in.(*look through the DOM inspector*)

Comment: Damm, could have seen it myself if i looked better. Thanks for the tipp.

Comment: What does Javascript do in this particulary example on the LOL page. The display status of the elements gets just changed?!? Do i miss someting?

Comment: If you think an answer solved your problem, please accept it (click the checkbox below the score).

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of ways.

The link you provided does so with Javascript.

While Javascript likely provides the most robust method / functionality - and since you asked if there is a pure CSS way, I wanted to share with you this pure CSS / HTML way.  Here is an example: [Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/hcnLr5sn/)

HTML:

```
<div>
  <label for="content1">First Button Text Here</label>
  <input id="content1" type="radio" name="content">
  <div>
    This is my content.
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="content2">Second Button Text Here</label>
  <input id="content2" type="radio" name="content">
  <div>
    This is my alternate content.
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="content3">Third Button Text Here</label>
  <input id="content3" type="radio" name="content">
  <div>
    This is my third set of content.
  </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background: #009;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

input + div {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 20px;
}

input:checked + div {
  display: block;
}
```

**IMPORTANT THINGS to watch for**
This markup will not work unless the following items are in place:
1. The labels for the radio button has a `for` attribute that matches exactly the `id` attribute of the radio buttons.  **The label does not have to be next to the button**, but could be separate as needed to get the layout desired.
2. The `div` that contains the content must be immediately after the `input`.  There cannot be any elements between them.

And, as a side-note, the `div` that contains the content can, if you like, contain a variety of rich markup to display sophisticated html such as images, tables, video embeds, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Gonna try it this way.

Comment: OK, note some of the items I am adding to the answer as things to watch for.

Answer (score 0):

IT would be nice if you could provide a link as an example (or at least images). But what you are describing can be achieved pretty simply by using jQuery and it's `.show()` and `.hide()` functions. Doing so, you can just create DOM elements you want (e.g. divs, videos, images, ...) and hide or show themn through jQuery.

Here a little example (to be honest, it's not the most fanciest one, but it works).

https://jsfiddle.net/fuzkoewj/